# C# Form store data into a list of objects

Tags: c#, .net

I am new to c# forms and I want to store some data from a textbox and 
a numericupdown with an 'Add' button into an object and then add that object to a list of objects so I can display that input later on with a 'Show' button.
Do you have any ideas how I can do that?

Comment: paste your form properties like textbox name, button name so I can help you more precise

Comment: I have a Textbox called 'Name' and a numericupdown 'Age',also I created a class Student which has the constructor Student(string name,byte age) ,button name 'Add' and button2 name 'Show' , and i am displaying all that info to a Listbox called 'myList' . I am not currently at my personal Pc where i have the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't fully clear from your question but I assume that you are trying to create a WinForm App. And you have a textBox which is called as Name (txtName will be a more efficient naming convention), a numericupdown as Age (nudAge) and a button as Add (btnAdd).

If you want to add a new student with entered values you should create a button click event for Add Button. (You can do that by double-clicking on the button on the design side of your form)

After that, with the following code, you can add a new student to _students list.

```
List<Student> _students = new List<Student>();

private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _students.Add(new Student(txtName.Text, (byte)nudAge.Value));
}
```

**UPDATE**

And assuming that your show button named as btnShow and listbox as lbStudents you can double click to show button to create a click event again.

After that, use the following code.

```
private void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var item in _students)
    {
        lbStudents.Items.Add(item.Name + " | " + item.Age);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Add a dataGridView as dgwStudents and replace the code in btnShow_Click with the following one.

```
dgwStudents.DataSource = _students;
```

Comment: And how can I display those students using the button 'btnShow" in a Listbox?

Comment: Alex, I updated my answer. But I should say it's not an efficient way to use listbox in this case. I would suggest using ListView to be able to show multiple columns.

Comment: Thanks for all the info,really helpful ,as soon as I get home I'll try it  and thanks for telling me about those naming conventions , I'll also try ListView as well, if you have other tips, please tell me if you can. Thanks again!

Comment: After checking the controls, I can say that it will be more easy to implement dataGridView for your case. So I updated my answer again for dataGridView.

Comment: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" I'm getting this error when i try to create a new student and add it to the list. Do you know what can I do to solve it?

Comment: At which step you got that error? Because it's a general error. Can you share the code?

Comment: I also had a comboBox and i had to figure out how to store it's data in an int variable, but I found a solution. Thanks!